# preg_replace: BB code to HTML URL

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I have a little script here which replaces BB code with HTML code. Everything works fine but the URLs.

```
$bbextended = array(
"/\[URL=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/URL\]/i" => "<a href=\"$1\" title=\"$1\">$2</a>"
);

foreach($bbextended as $match=>$replacement){
$bbtext = preg_replace($match, $replacement, $bbtext);
}
```

Input

```
[URL="http://somewebsite.come/something"]Some Website Title[/URL]
```

Output

```
<a href=""http://somewebsite.come/something"" title=""http://somewebsite.come/something"">Some Website Title</a>
```

There are double-quotes, which obviously isn't that good.

I tried

```
$bbextended = array(
"/\[URL=\"(.*?)\"\](.*?)\[\/URL\]/i" => "<a href=\"$1\" title=\"$1\">$2</a>"
);
```

in the code but it didn't work. I also tried to leave out the escape sign and quotes around the `$1` in the HTML code but it didn't work neither.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a real parser for this, such as jBB http://jbbcode.com/

Answer (score 0):

When I

Set the Find string = `'/\[URL="(.*?)"\](.*?)\[\/URL\]/i'`
and
Set the replace string = `'<a href="$1" title="$1">$2</a>'`

I get this using simple preg_replace

```
<a href="http://somewebsite.come/something" title="http://somewebsite.come/something">Some Website Title</a>
```